# Версия этого файла несовместима с используемой версией Windows

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, windows-7

У меня стоит 64 битая винда, программу писал на этой винде, сейчас попытался на 32 битной запустить выдает ошибку

```
Версия этого файла несовместима с используемой версией Windows. С помощью сведений о системе определите необходимую версию программы (32- или 64-разрядную) и обратитесь к издателю программного обеспечения
```

Есть ли способ сделать и под 64 и под 32 бита(мб настройки в visual studio подкрутить какие-нибудь)

Comment: А собираете проект как? AnyCPU или под определенный?

Comment: Соберите свое приложение под x86 процессор.

Comment: 64-битные приложения запускаются только на 64-битном компе, а 32-битные и на 64- и на 32-битном

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Честно, вообще не знаю, у меня собирается все автоматически, я просто код пишу

Comment: @aepot Как это сделать, мб гайд есть?

Comment: 30 секунд гугления, и [вот что](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-building-an-application?view=vs-2017) нашлось.